# Get-Child Item not working through task scheduler

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this script through GPO deployed scheduled task:

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\Software\CC\PST_Discovery_Script\Already_Run'

if  (!(Test-Path -Path $registryPath)) {

            $dir = "c:\Users"
            $ext = "pst" 
            Get-ChildItem "$dir" *$ext -r | Select-Object FullName,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime,CreationTime,@{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}, @{Name="MegaBytes"; Expression={"{0:F2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)}}, @{N='Hostname';E={$env:computername}} | export-csv "c:\PST_Discovery.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation 

   New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\CC\PST_Discovery_Script -Name Already_Run –Force

}
```

[image: Scheduled task]

It works fine if I run the script manually through the Powershell console/ISE, but not through a scheduled task.

If I run it through a scheduled task, I know the script is running because it reads the registry key, and if it doesn't exist it writes a registry key, but it does't actually run the get-childitem line or export a CSV.

The scheduled task shows up on the client, and it's running using a Domain Admin credentials (me)

EDIT: Sorry, my formatting for the code went all wrong, i think it should be fixed up now

**kaspermoerch**: Yes, it's a domain admin, and thus has full permissions over the file system

**boxdog**: I actually had it writing to a UNC share, but changed it to local computer because it wasn't working. I'll try some other combinations of output location and user.

**TheIncorrigible**: Originally it was system, but it wasn't working so I edited the pushed out scheduled task and am using my domain admin account.

**Adam**:
- Yes, scheduled task is created
- Yes, task runs script using following code: Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass \server1\share1\PST_Discovery_Script.ps1
- Yes, it runs using my DA creds
- Yes, the file isn't created, though it still writes the registry value

I've checked scheduled task, see my screenshot. I'm elevating the task scheduler and manually running the task.

Comment: Have you checked that the account running the scheduled task has the required permissions on the file system?

Comment: It is very likely a permissions issue.  Does it work with a different user, different target folder, different CSV output location, etc?  Try to narrow down what is actually failing, as there seem to be several possible places.

Comment: `$dir = "c:\Users"`

Comment: Why are you running it as your domain account (IN A GPO) instead of system? @Matt It's defined in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand correctly.

- The scheduled task is created.
- The scheduled task runs a script containing the following code.
- The scheduled task executes the script using your credentials.
- Your account is in the Domain Admin group.
- By "not working", the `PST_Discovery.csv` file isn't created.

Correct me if I misunderstood anything.

First: I'd verify the scheduled task is running in an elevated context (runas administrator). Even if the account executing the task is an administrator, the job needs to run in an elevated context.

[image]

Second: I'm curious how this works for you but not me. I've never seen a call to `Select-Object` quite like you've got. If I try to pipe an `gci | Select-Object -Property @(...what you have...) | Export-Csv...` I get an exception complaining about the `FullName`.

```
$registryPath = 'HKLM:\Software\CC\PST_Discovery_Script\Already_Run'

if (!(Test-Path -Path $registryPath)) {
    $dir = 'c:\Users'
    $ext = 'pst'
    Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter *$ext -Recurse |
        Select-Object -Property @(
            FullName
            LastAccessTime
            LastWriteTime
            CreationTime
            @{N = 'Owner'; E = {$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}
            @{Name = "MegaBytes"; Expression = {"{0:F2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)}}
            @{N = 'Hostname'; E = {$env:computername}}
        ) |
        Export-Csv -Path c:\PST_Discovery.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
    New-Item -Path HKLM:\Software\CC\PST_Discovery_Script -Name Already_Run –Force
}
```

You're 100% sure that works? I had to change that snippet to the following:

```
Select-Object -Property @(
, 'FullName'
, 'LastAccessTime'
, 'LastWriteTime'
, 'CreationTime'
@{N = 'Owner'; E = {$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}
@{Name = "MegaBytes"; Expression = {"{0:F2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)}}
@{N = 'Hostname'; E = {$env:computername}}
```

I'm running Powershell 5 on Windows 10. I'm executing your example from the CLI.

Comment: My code formatting got messed up, it should be ok now,

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code format you laid out, and it worked fine for me.

A quick and easy method to capture anything going wrong would be to change the error action preference to stop at the start of your script so that the process exits at the first error and any errors will flow back to the scheduled task's Last Run Result. From there you should be able to see the exception.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

That should at least provide a starting point if you haven't already solved it. If that returns anything other than 0, then you know to build in some error handling with `try/catch` and perhaps an output log, to help you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Did you run it in a scheduled task? What options did you have? Thanks, I'll try your suggestions.

Comment: I ran it as a scheduled task with the same options you have indicated. This tells me that there is something else going on, and you will need to debug the actual script that's running by building in logging functionality to ensure any exception messages are written somewhere for you to check over. Good luck!